# initializing radio buttons added dynamically in materialize

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I have an ajax request that generates a modal window with radio buttons dynamically.

I see in the [materialize documentation](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) that you can execute `material_select()` to get `selects` working correctly however, I don't see in the documentation how to initialize a `radio` dynamically.

**How do i initialize dynamically loaded radio buttons?**

For reference here is in example modal that I am loading dynamically:

```
<div id="import-modal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Import Data</h4>
        <p>
            <input name="import-group" type="radio" id="import-modal-csv"/>
            <label for="import-modal-csv">Csv</label>
            <div>Import a csv file.</div>
        <p/>
        <p>
            <input name="import-group" type="radio" id="import-modal-excel"/>
            <label for="import-modal-excel">Excel</label>
            <div>Import a excel file.</div>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Import</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**edit 1**

i'm adding the above div dynamically via `jquery` to a parent container on `click` of a button:

```
        import_click: function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'template/import.html',
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#container').append(response);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: what do you want to add in Radio Button

Comment: @ShubhamPatel i dont want to add anything to the radio button.  It isn't displaying the visual effects that you see in the documentation when added dynamically.  On a select, to fix this, you initialize the element with the `material_select()` method.  I'm wondering what/if there is a method to call to initialize the radio button to get the effects working.

Comment: you are loading it with jQuery or something else

Comment: @ShubhamPatel yeah, i load the div dynamically with jquery, added the controller function that appends the div to the original question if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

The radio buttons do not require any javascript initialization. Just make sure when you append them dynamically to give them new ID's because if they conflict with existing radio buttons, they will not work.

Comment: thanks, i'll check it out when i get home.  I'm wondering if maybe the [awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/) browser i'm using is maybe causing my issue then.  I think it's based on an older version of chrome.